# Passing value via URL to controller from JSP in Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Created an application. Page A displays a droplist containing list of values. If user clicks on particular account, will display a chart. We have similar button right to the acccount droplist. Those are separate JSP's. If user clicks on Page A, then selected account name should move to those 4 jsp page. I have tried via URL. But not getting. Please help.

JSP 1

```
<a id="priorityCallAnalysis" class="item"> <button type ="button" onclick="getPriorityCall()">Priority </button> </a>
<form:form action="somepage" method="post" commandName="somedata"
                id="taskDetails" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Choose Account*</label>
                            <form:select path="accountName" class="form-control"
                                id="accountName" onchange="getDashboard()">

                                <form:option value="" label="--select--"></form:option>
                                <c:forEach items="${accountList}" var="accountName">
                                    <form:option value="${accountName}" label="${accountName}"></form:option>
                                </c:forEach>


                            </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form:form>

function getPriorityCall()
{
    var accountName = $("#accountName").val();
    alert(accountName);
    window.location="priorityCall.html?accountName="+accountName+"";
}
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/priorityCall")
    public ModelAndView priorityCall(Map<String, Object> model,@RequestParam ("accountName") String accName)
    {
        System.out.println("entry");
        SampleBean template = new SampleBean ();
        model.put("template ", template );
        List<String> accountList = Service.getAccountList();
        model.put("accountList", accountList);
        model.put("accName", accName);

        return new ModelAndView("analByPrior","","");
    }
```

JSP : analByPrior

```
<form:form action="#" method="post" commandName="somedata"
                id="taskDetails" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Choose Account*</label>
                            <form:select path="accountName" class="form-control"
                            id="accountName" onchange="getAssignmentGroups()">
                            <form:option value="" label="--select--"></form:option>
                            <c:forEach items="${accountList}" var="accName">
                        <form:option value="${accName}" selected="true"> ${accName}</form:option>
                            </c:forEach>

                        </form:select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form:form>
```

**UPDATE**
While clicking on Priority Button, this controller is getting called, instead of PriorityCall.. I dont know y..

```
@RequestMapping("/priorityCallAnalysis")
    public String someAction(@ModelAttribute("accountName") TicketInfo data, Map<String, Object> map,
                                    HttpServletRequest request) {

        TicketInfo somedata = new TicketInfo();
            map.put("somedata",somedata);
            System.out.println(somedata);
           System.out.println("acc=" + request.getParameter("accountName"));

           /* do some process and send back the data */
            map.put("somedata", data);
            map.put("accountName", request.getParameter("accountName"));

            return "analysisByPriority";
       }
```

Comment: Just to check, in the `javascript` code the priorityCall url is `priorityCall.html` whilst in the controller the `@RequestMapping` value is just `/priorityCall` without the `.html` suffix. Is it correct?

Comment: I think Yes. We can pass like tat. @jlumietu

Comment: Did you test removing the `.html`suffix from the `js` function, just calling `"priorityCall?accountName="+accountName+""` ? I would test that, as it is the easiest solution to try...

Comment: tried now.. not working.. is this flow is right first of all??... Im confused.. totaly...

Comment: When you are calling window.location you need to give you context path in the url, like  '/<appname>/priorityCall/' + "?accountName=" + accountName and no html, as window.location will replace the url in the browser.

Comment: Giving 404 error  @AmitKBist

Comment: can you hit this url directly in browser and check if it hitting your controller, http://localhost:<portnumber>/{appName}/priorityCall?accountName={acountName}

Comment: Also check server logs when hitting above url, and share those logs please

Comment: If I tried like this.. it is hitting the controller, and related jsp is getting displayed. But that selected droplist is not displaying there. It is taking the last droplist value. Please look into analByPrior jsp, which I mentioned above, and tell me If am wrong anywhere there.                                                 1. Y it is not passing value via URI? @AmitKBist

Comment: accountNameFromServer is not set in your model in controller, you are setting accountName but comparing it with accountNameFromServer which is never set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156872/discussion-between-bhuvana-k-and-amit-k-bist).

Comment: Logs: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [17/Oct/2017:09:50:45 +0530] "GET /SampleApp/priorityCall?accountName={XXX} HTTP/1.1" 200 2**** @AmitKBist

Comment: So all good? Everything working fine now?

Comment: No.. 1. while hitting url directly, It is moving to that jsp 2. And also selected accountName is not passing. In analByPrior.jsp, it is displaying the last droplist value.. not the selected one. @AmitKBist

Answer (score 0):

First in the **.jsp file** you can use a global variable to store context path and use this variable as prefix in all the relative paths.

```
<script>var context = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}"</script>
```

Now within your js function use the context path and call the controller.

```
function getPriorityCall(){
  var accountName = $("#accountName").val();
  alert("contextPath: "+context); // will print your {appName}
  window.location=context+"/priorityCall?accountName="+accountName;
}
```

So your URI looks like below in your request call.

```
http://localhost:8080/{appName}/priorityCall?accountName={acountName}
```

PS:

- benefit of use this `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is if you change your appName later you dont need to change it in views. It will automatically get the latest contextPath.
- If you are using Firefow browser install the firebug add-on and Use it for to verify your requests. So you can validate your URI with params.(If its chrome use Inspect Element to validate URI)

Comment: Ok to nearly all... but just one thing. A `window.location` won't perform a POST request but a GET one instead

Comment: @jlumietu Thanks for your output. Glad to know that and I'll update the answer based on that

Comment: Are you using tomcat as server? What is the .war file name deployed to the server? .war file name and appName should be similar. Also for select the selectedAccName in jsp. You need to set it to the model first within controller. model.put(“selectedAccName”, accountName);  Then within the jsp you have to get this value and compare it with each array list value while you are looping the accountList. When the both values are equal set the selected=“true” attribute for that option. For other cases populate the option without selected attribute.

Comment: 1. how to find the war file name?..  2. In priorityCall, Im passing the value as accountName and I am setting it to the model within controller like model.put("accountName", accountName); Then too i am getting 404 error. Pls help @Neero